# I want to be signaled when app found user location.

Tags: ios, gps, mkmapview

I use MKMapView.

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

I want to be signaled when app found user location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle that event in mapview delegate's `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` method - it is called each time user location is updated

Answer (score 2):

Simple.

Implement the `MKMapViewDelegate` method [`-mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView%3adidUpdateUserLocation%3a).

Answer (score 2):

For this, you have to  implement the delegate method :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
```

And set you class as the delegate of you mapView :

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```

If you prefer, you may also do that into IB.

Your class has to reference the MKMapViewDelegate protocol :

```
@interface YourClass : InheritanceObject <MKMapViewDelegate> {
     MKMapView* mapView;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView* mapView; // IBOutlet if you create the mapView into IB
```